# How to make a slower timer? (Python)

Tags: python, timer, counter

I'm fairly new to using Python, and I'm trying to get a hit timer so that in my game when my player is hit, it needs to wait a couple seconds before he can be hit again.

I thought I could just do something like:

```
while hitTimer > 0:
    hitTimer -= 1
```

and being hit resets the counter to `10`, and requiring the counter to be `> 0` to be able to be hit again, but it goes way to fast.

I tried using very small numbers like `-= .00005` but that just makes my program lag bad.

How can I make it so it takes away 1 per second or something like that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to check for exactly 10 seconds, do this:

```
import time
# record when person was first hit.
previousHit = time.time()

if time.time() - previousHit > 10:
    # The rest of your logic for getting hit.
    previousHit = time.time() # Reset the timer to get the hit again.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `time.clock()` to check the time and `time.sleep()` to wait.

Never rely on CPU speed for timing code.

Comment: One problem I see is that this seems to pause the execution, the player and game should still be able to go on with it.

Comment: Then you can use threading, or (an uglier solution) busy-wait until the time is right.

Answer (score 1):

You just record the time someone was hit, using `time.time()`:

```
import time

lastHit = time.time()
```

And then compare the current time against `lastHit`:

```
if time.time() - lastHit > NUMBER_OF_SECONDS:
  # ... do seomthing about getting hit ...
  lastHit = time.time()
```